# Quit Safari app automatically after closing tabs

Tags: macos, safari

I come at macs from a windows perspective and it bothers me that Safari stays open after I've closed all tabs. I don't like needing to then go and either quit from the top bar or cmd-click-quit the app in the dock.

I've seen that there's a way in the terminal to close the app, but that's just as much work as closing it manually. I want it to automatically close when there are no open tabs.

**Is there a way to switch Safari's settings so when no tabs are open, the app quits?**

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/53935/getting-mac-os-x-applications-to-close-after-last-window-closed

Comment: Cmd/q is all you need to learn. All multi-sheet Mac apps work that way, & always have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can force quit safari easily by holding down the Control key and then clicking on the icon on your Dock. Once the sub menu comes up, click on Quit.

Comment: Why not just command+q key combo?

Comment: That works too but most people are GUI driven. Clicking that keyboard combo can be dangerous. I'd rather people click the red circle with the x inside. It's just safer. But nice for the pros.

Answer (score 1):

Once you close all the tabs, you are still "in" Safari. What you can do is simply press command+Q and that is it.